# Meterpreter reverse_https ExitOnSession

Tags: http, metasploit, meterpreter

When I'm setting the options for the `reverse_https` handler in metasploit, why would I set `ExitOnSession` to false and `SessionCommunicationTimeout` to 0? I don't fully understand the purpose. When I used those options it just kept opening meterpreter sessions until I closed the handler. And when `ExitOnSession` is false, why can I only use `exploit -j` and not exploit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I'm setting the options for the reverse_https handler in
>   metasploit why would I set ExitOnSession to false and
>   SessionCommunicationTimeout to 0, and don't [fully] understand the
>   purpose.

If `SessionCommunicationTimeout` is 0:

> setting this to 0 will result in a session that will never timeout,
>   which has some interesting uses

It will keep connecting back using the connection to the HTTPS endpoint.

> And why when ExitOnSession is false I can only use exploit -j and not
>   exploit?

Because the handler can continue running as a job, even in the case of a closed, or failed meterpreter session. It only applies to jobs(-j) as these are the only ones that run in the background.

For more info, see [here](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2011/06/29/meterpreter-httphttps-communication).

Answer (score 1):

If you set your multi handler to migrate processes on session creation and set exitonsession to true, it will create one session, migrate the process, close the port, and stop the creation of a ton of sessions.

that might do the trick.